# Equivalent VBScript code is needed for the example in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, vbscript, dhtml

I have the below code in JavaScript. I want to have equivalent code in VBScript. I have tried some examples but they never work for me: document.getElementById("button1").onclick = FuncHello;

Can you provide me equivalent VBScript client-side code ?

```
<head>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    window.onload = initAll;

    function initAll()
    {
        document.getElementById("button1").onclick = FuncHello;
    }

    function FuncHello()
    {
        document.write ("Hello");
    }

    </script>

</head>

<body>

    <form name="form1">

        <input type="button" id="button1" value="Hello">

    </form>

</body>
```

Here is the Client-side code in VBScript, I do Have:

```
<head>

    <script type="text/vbscript">

    window.onload = initAll

    Sub initAll()

        document.getElementById("button1").onclick = FuncHello

    End Sub

    Sub FuncHello()

        document.write ("Hello")

    End Sub

    </script>

</head>

<body>

    <form name="form1">

        <input type="button" id="button1" value="Hello">

    </form>

</body>
```

Comment: So where `FuncHello` defined? Without that, this code could never work. And beyond this, we are not a code translation service. YOU translate the code, we'll maybe help try fix it.

Comment: <html>

 <head>

  <script type="text/vbscript">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested, just from memory

```
<script type="text/vbscript">
function initAll()
    set document.getElementById("button1").onclick = GetRef("FuncHello")
end function

function FunHello
  ....
end function

set window.onload = GetRef("initAll")
</script>
```